# How can i make my MSI file hosted to my Website

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

On many sites we will have an option to download setup files from the site directly. How to do this. I need to add both Zip files and setup file to my website so that when user clicks on it it should be downloaded for installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload the .msi and the .zip to the server and link to them. This should be very simple unless I'm missing something.

Comment: There would also likely need to be some IIS server changes to allow serving of those types of files.

Comment: @StefanH does IIS have rules about that type of stuff? I guess I'm spoiled by Apache

Comment: Yes, and I'm pretty sure Apache does to.  You are certainly able to tell Apache to serve even unknown mime types, but I'm pretty sure it does not do it by default.